# Elasticsearch regex searching

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, nginx

I'm trying to use `regex` finding `html tags` inside my `nginx` logs. My queries:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
       "request": "script"
      }
    }
 }
```

It returns me every `script` words as I expected.

```
1.1.1.1 - - [18/Feb/2018:18:24:00 +0300] "GET /some/path/script-writing-i HTTP/1.1" 200 31712 0.085 0.085 ."-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)" "-"

1.1.1.1 - - [09/Feb/2018:00:44:15 +0300] "GET /some/path\x22><script>alert(303);</script>=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 64183 0.104 0.104 ."-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)" "-"
```

What I want that finding expressions with some html tag, specially `script` tag. When I try with Regex101 `(=)[^\n]*(<)[^\n]+(>)`, I can find what I want, but it comes to Elasticsearch, it throws `query_shard_exception`.

Any suggestion or help would be great!

Comment: How are you indexing this data? Could you provide us your document mapping? 
In other hand characters `<` | `>` are reserved characters , you need to scape them.  
Check : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators

Comment: we checked the reference but we couldn't find anything there. How can i search `<script>` with regex in Elasticsearch?

Comment: The problem resides in how you're indexing your data, if you share mapping settings I can guess what you can do to extract `<script>` .